# passing parameter to view give infinite loop / page refresh in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem with CodeIgniter 3.
When I try to access URL with the parameter like these `http://localhost/crm/Customer/update/3`

The result is infinite loop page refresh.
This does not happen if I access other view or URL.

For example : `http://localhost/crm/Customer/list`

Below is my controller file :

```
class Customer extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'customer'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model(array('Auth', 'Model_customer'));
        $this->_init();
    }

    function _init() {

        $this->output->set_template('index');
        // $this->load->section('sidebar','template/sidebar');
    }

    public function index(){
        ...
        $this->load->view('customer/index');
    }

    function update($id) {

        // TEST
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->load->view('customer/update2', $data);
    }
}
```

Any help will be valuable. Thanks

Comment: can you post here the content of your view update2.php

Comment: btw it's just simple html tag. no variable

Comment: What the heck is `output->set_template`? The output class of CI has no such method.

Comment: What routes you have defined for this function?

Comment: output->set_template is custom library. 
// this is my route config
$route['default_controller'] = 'User';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['Customer/update/(:num)'] = 'Customer/update/$1';

Comment: **list** is a reserved word in PHP

Comment: @YadhuBabu that route is just madeup example. :)